# How to style component's host when child element is not hidden?

Tags: angular, sass

I have an image preview component, and I want to stop the app-component from scrolling when the preview isn't hidden. Is there a scss/css-only way to do this?

I've figured out that I can stop the page from scrolling if I set `app-component`'s `overflow` property to `hidden` with the `:host` pseudoclass. I tried the following code:

```
.preview[hidden=false] {
    & {
        :host {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing happened. I tried that with another `&` and nothing changed.

The preview component looks like this within its parent.

The page should scroll behind the preview only when it's hidden. It's scrolling no matter what. Is this possible with SCSS?

Comment: try :host-context https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context

Comment: `:host-context` looks up the tree to ancestors and parents. I need a way to look at children and style the host based on their attribute(s).

Comment: what about ::ng-deep?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it with a property and a class attribute.

app.component.html

```
<div [class.opened]="open"> //wrapper for app component
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.opened{
   height: 500px; // set it again 
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbsb8p)